# Unitary representation of Euclidean Group in 1-dimension $E(1)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

What is the unitary representation of $E(1)$, the non-compact Euclidean group in 1-dimension. Translation AND reflection on the real line.

- How to construct it?
- How does it look like (which operator on which space)?
- Can we induce it from the translation only group representation?

Comment: You want reflexions R, a π rotation in phase-space, represented by generators $\hat p$ of the translation operator  without $\hat x$??

Comment: I want translation and reflection in a point. It should be twice bigger than the additive group of the real line.

Comment: My answer reflects around zero, but the point may be chosen arbitrarily, *b* =0, by changing coordinates to $x'=x-b$ so $R ~x'=-x'$.

Comment: Now I see that your answer is correct but I'm a bit confused. Should we better have to act on a kind of two-side function space ? I would like to know where is something and if it's a "right or left" thing. I don't know how to explain.

Comment: There is nothing R-L, really, but that's what unitarity, a property of the adjoint,  is all about: I could transcribe all this as acting on functions, if I dot al ket-bra operators with  $\langle f| \cdot |f\rangle$.

Comment: So I just have to put R in the middle to extract the handedness ? But, for example, how I can superpose a "right gaussian density function" with a left one and observe the p=1/2 ?

Comment: ? handedness? I am using parity which is self-adjoint, unlike translations which are not...

Comment: I don't understand. I would like the particle to have a density probability of being somewhere together with a discrete probability of being looking to the right or to the left and perform any superposition. Can you show me ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. You may think of f(x), g(x) as real wavefunctions in one dimension, and R the reflection operator.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to use a two component vector of wavefunctions so I can swap them for R and translate them in opposite way both when T ?

Comment: You need to add more context in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully appreciate your objective, but if you want to stay (deceptively) real,  as a lark, here is a unitary representation on *just* the real line, of reflections *R* and translations *T(a)*,
$$
R=\int \!\!dx~ |-x\rangle \langle x|, \qquad T(a)= \int \!\!dx~ |x\rangle e^{-a\partial_x}\langle x|,
$$
which reflect and translate the arguments of $f(x)=\langle x|f\rangle$.

(As per your comment/question, if you wish to bypass Dirac notation,
$$\int\!dx ~g(x)Rf(x)= \int\!dx ~g(x)f(-x)=\int\!dx~ g(-x)f(x)\\
\int\!dx ~g(x)T(a)f(x)=\int\!dx ~g(x)f(x+a)=\int\!dx ~g(x-a)f(x)~~~.)  $$

Through sequential integrations by parts and collapses of delta functions, you may  confirm that, indeed,
$$
R~T(a)~R~ T(a)\\ = \int \!\!dxdydzdw~ (|-x\rangle \langle x|)(|y\rangle e^{-a\partial_y}\langle y|)(|-z\rangle \langle z|)(|w\rangle e^{-a\partial_w} \langle w|)\\ = 
\int\!\!dxdw~ |-x\rangle (e^{-a\partial_w}\delta (x+w)) e^{-a\partial_w}\langle w| =\int\!\! dw~ | w\rangle \langle w|  =I,
$$
as required.

Comment: Thank you. Should I put the a before the derivative in the translation operator ?

Comment: Right you are; thanks; did it.